# Azure DevOps Server - How to migrate existing collection/project to SCRUM

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We did upgrade TFS 2013 Update 2 to Azure DevOps Server (on-premises), we don't know exactly which Template all of our collections use but we would like to convert it to SCRUM.

Is it possible to convert our existing projects/collections to this template?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Are you using Work items yet? If not then we could change the project to be scrum but it will take a little work, you'll need to delete work items (if you have some and don't care about them), delete the work item types, add the scrum work item types (from an exported scrum project), change the processconfig to the new types and it would now be "scrum".  Let me know if you need help.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I was taking more time to properly understand your answer but it's the correct one. I'll mark as correct one, thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert our existing projects/collections to this template?

I am afraid it is impossible to achieve that.

According to official documentation, we could to know:

> You can change the process a team project uses from a system process
>   or inherited process to an inherited process. **You can only change team
>   projects to use another process that inherits from the same system
>   process.** That is, you can change an Agile-based team project to any
>   process you created from the Agile system process as well as to the
>   Agile process. Whereas, you can't change a Scrum-based team project to
>   an Agile-derived inherited process.

So, it is not possible to convert process templates for your existing projects/collections in Azure DevOps Server.

You could create a new projects/collections based on SCRUM and then move your source code and workitems to that new projects/collections. For source control you could always branch out from a stable version, and keep the old project around. That way you will keep you source history. For work items, you can export them to Excel, create a new Excel connection to Azure DevOps Server, that is connected to the new team project, and then copy the workitems and pushing them from the new Excel file into the new project.

BTW, you can learn to use `witadmin` to change things, but that isn't a best practice if you have workitems in the team projects:

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823864/steps-for-changing-process-template-for-an-existing-project-in-tfs-2010) for some details.

Hope this helps.